# How to best fill this?

Tags: bevel

I basically want to fill the space between the circle and the cylinder-like shape. How can I do it? Selecting all edges and F doesn't work (BTW, selecting with alt an edge at the top of the cylinder doesn't select all the loop, why)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> right click doesn't select the edge loop because you have single vertices in the middle of the edge loop, first dissolve them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.

To bridge the edges you can select them both and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> (or *Edge* panel) > *Bridge Edge Loops*. You can tweak some factors in the *Operator* box if necessary (bottom left of your 3D view).

You could also extrude up the top edge loop and right click > *LoopTools > Circle* (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *To Sphere*).

Comment: I'm voting for last option :)

Comment: He may have reasons to keep his current circle, I don't know

Comment: Sure ... I was partly joking, partly suggested because of preventing topo issues ... Nothing against to you :) Nice widely covering answer.

Comment: no problem, I didn't feel offended  ;)  it's just that sometimes, as you're never sure of the context, it's better to give a proper answer + suggest something else